# Impossible to write correct type signature

Tags: f#

I'm playing around with some overloading in F#.
I have a function with a static type constraint that specifies the type `^a` should have a static member `f` of the type `unit -> ^a`.

I also want my function to work with native types, but since they don't have that member and since static constraints don't work for type extensions, I resorted to some hackery. Here's what I did.

```
let inline gInternal< ^a, ^b when (^a or ^b) : (static member f : ^a -> ^a)> (b : ^b) : ^a
    = ((^a or ^b) : (static member f: ^a -> ^a) (Unchecked.defaultof< ^a>))

let inline g() : ^a = gInternal Default
```

Here, `Default` is an object of type `Default` defined like this

```
type Default =
    | Default
    static member f(_ : unit) = ()
    static member f(_ : int) = 0
```

I was a bit surprised that this actually worked, but now I have a different issue.
I wanted to make a signature file for this module. Unfortunately, the signature for `g` becomes impossible to write.

It's type should be

```
val g< ^a when (^a or Default) : (static member f: ^a -> ^a)> : unit -> ^a
```

but the `^a or Default` part isn't valid syntactically.
Is there any other way to express this?

Comment: The question is different, but the answer applies. Seems that it's a bug in F#.